# What does it mean to protect RNA polymerase?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, transcription

From this [paper](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep02347)

> However, based on the strong interaction between NusA and RNAP, we propose that the chaperone activity of NusA could provide more direct and concentrated protection for RNAP under stress, i.e., NusA could simultaneously act as a latent **protector** of RNAP during transcription elongation and termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "protection" the authors mean that in the presence of NusA, some proteins are less prone to aggregation after heat shock. "Protection", in general, could also refer to stabilization i.e. reduction in the degradation rates of the protein.

> To detect the influence of NusA on heat-induced aggregation, we used
> lactate dehydrogenase (LDH). LDH was incubated at 48°C in the absence
> or presence of NusA. As shown in Fig. 2b, LDH slowly aggregated at
> 48°C without the protection of NusA. However, when this experiment was
> performed in the presence of NusA, aggregation was visibly reduced.
> These results suggest that NusA also **protects** unfolded proteins from
> irreversible aggregation during thermal stress.
>
> ...
> ...
> In E. coli, RpoA and RpoB, the major components of RNAP, are prone to
> aggregation under heat stress in vivo. They were reported to interact
> with GroEL and DnaK, mainly for the **protection from aggregation** or
> refolding into a nonnative state<sup>48,49</sup>. However, based on the strong
> interaction between NusA and RNAP, we propose that the chaperone
> activity of NusA could provide more direct and concentrated protection
> for RNAP under stress, i.e., NusA could simultaneously act as a latent
> protector of RNAP during transcription elongation and termination.